# Preventing UIPopoverController from covering ADBannerView

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, iad

I have PhotoViewController that contains OverlayView and ADBannerView. OverlayView has some buttons which display UIPopoverControllers. Sometimes this popovers display over ADBannerView and I get a warning:

> WARNING A banner view (0x193930) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

Is there a way to display popover in my predefined position or is popover able to recognize that sometimes it would cover ADBannerView?

Comment: I found out that it's not because popover panel covers ADBannerView, but it's because whole screen is taken by popover and ad cannot be clicked.

So my question is: will this behaviour have negative consequences such as displaying less ads from apple or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's not because popover panel covers ADBannerView, but it's because whole screen is taken by popover and ad cannot be clicked. I've heard that it's not a problem, because hovering is not purposely hiding, but triggerd by user action.